# EntityFramework / Get two objects from database with lowest price

Tags: database, entity-framework, methods, repository

Im working on a web api project. Im using *Dependency Injection* so im creating all my methods in my `ProductRepository` class. Specificly `public IQueryable<Product> GetTwoWithLowestPrice()` method.

What i need to achieve is returning 2 products with the lowest price from the database.

I tried to get all the products from the database and **sort them ascending**, which would mean that **2 products with lowest price** would be **at the beginning** of this `sorted` list. Hence I'm adding products on `index` position 0 and 1 (first two) to my `retVal` list... Im probably not allowed to cast lists into different collections so easily without losing data (im not THAT familiar with every collection out there). Code:

```
 public  IQueryable<Product> GetTwoWithLowestPrice()
        {
            List<Product> retVal = new List<Product>();

            var sorted = db.Products.Include(p => p.Category).OrderBy(p => p.Price);

            var list = sorted as List<Product>;

            retVal.Add(list[0]);
            retVal.Add(list[1]);


            return retVal as IQueryable<Product>;

        }
```

This throws exception

```
('Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'   list was null.)
```

Comment: Although your thought process may work initially (getting records from the database, then ordering them by to get the lowest price), if in the future you have a substantial amount of products, you may be having to return and sort a large dataset.
It would almost always be more efficient to use a database query to retrieve the 2 lowest prices.

Comment: @Leroy I thought of this, but im looking for an alternative/quicker way (using EntitiyFramework). But anyway, how would you do it? With `string` query, `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` ? That is the only way i've learned so far to get the data from the database.

Comment: The answer to this depends on your database of choice as the SQL query would change based upon this.
A simple example would be:

`SELECT TOP 2 product FROM products ORDER BY price ASC`

Of course, the above SQL table/field names should be changed to match what your database contains.

Comment: @Leroy Understood. Although i need to find out if this could be done using EntityFramework somehow

Comment: Use Take and ToList. But in general: try to understand what you're doing instead of trial-and-error programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example looks to be mix-mashing a number of techniques/practices unnecessarily.

First off:

```
public  IQueryable<Product> GetTwoWithLowestPrice()
```

`IQueryable` is an interface to expose data in a way that Linq can query across. It is an extremely powerful type that can allow you to simplify return types, especially EF Entities in a manner that callers which understand the data can further reduce or consume it in any number of ways. Normally this would be used in something like a Repository pattern for a method like:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
```

or even:

```
public IQueryable<Product> GetProductById(int productId)
```

The reason for having a method like this can be to centralize fundamental rules about your data. Such as returning only Active products by default, or performing base level rules like enforcing a user can only receive products that apply to them. It may seem strange to return `IQueryable<Product>` even for a method that is expected to return a single product, but it allows the caller to streamline the query:

Does a product exist?

```
bool exists = repository.GetProductById(productId).Any();
```

Rather than using EF to load an entire entity just to later check if it's Null or not.

It also allows you to project the data using `Select` to streamline the query down to selecting just the data you care about. I.e. if you're populating a list of products and just need the product ID, Name, and price:

```
var productList = repository.GetProducts()
    .Select(x => new ProductSummaryViewModel
    {
        ProductId = x.ProductId,
        Name = x.Name,
        Price = x.Price
    }).ToList();
```

Add to that support for sorting, pagination, etc.  The same applies to the "ById", you can leverage `IQueryable` to project the entity and its relatives down to just the values you need.

Given you have a method that is designed to only return the 2 cheapest products, `IQueryable` isn't really a useful return type. I'd just return an `IEnumerable`.

```
public  IEnumerable<Product> GetTwoWithLowestPrice()
{
```

The next thing would be to leverage Linq to Order and Take the two cheapest products. For your code:

```
var list = sorted as List<Product>;

retVal.Add(list[0]);
retVal.Add(list[1]);
```

at the bare minimum would have needed to be:

```
var list = sorted.ToList();

retVal.Add(list[0]);
retVal.Add(list[1]);
```

However, this is a very costly mistake as you are telling EF to return ***ALL*** Products when you only want the first two. Linq and EF can accommodate this with `Take`.

```
public  IEnumerable<Product> GetTwoWithLowestPrice()
{
    var products = db.Products
        .Include(p => p.Category)
        .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
        .Take(2)
        .ToList();

    return products;
}
```

And that is it. This will return the 0-2 cheapest products, including their category, and the query will only return those 0-2 rows.

Overall this is a very specific scenario method, and if this is a repository I'd probably consider leaving the specific scenario logic in the controller rather than having a growing number of specific methods in the data translation layer. This requires elevating the DbContext or Unit of Work to the Controller/Presenter.

So using the previous `IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()` in a repository, the controller code that wants the cheapest two products would look like:

```
var products = _repository.GetProducts()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
    .Select(x => new ProductSummaryViewModel
    {
        ProductId = x.ProductId,
        Name = x.Name,
        Price = x.Price,
        CategoryName = x.Category.Name
    }).Take(2)
    .ToList();
```

The advantage of this will be that projection (`Select`) will build a query that only retrieves the necessary fields, including related ones (x.Category.Name) rather than loading *all* columns from Product and its associated Category. (note that `.Include` is not needed when using `Select`) I highly recommend using ViewModels that contain just enough info that the view needs rather than returning entire entities, especially with related entities to views. It saves memory, results in faster queries, and are faster to transfer over the wire. It also exposes less about your data structure for would-be attackers.

That's a bit of a run down on how to leverage EF and Linq to get desired sets of data.

Comment: Thank you, this explains a lot. I knew my approach was bad definitely. Question: I will also have other methods ex `GetAllWithPriceLowerThan(decimal price)` or `GetAllByCategoryId(int categoryId)` .Is using `IEnumerable<Product>` as a `return value` for  the mentioned the way to go?

Comment: You can use either, though it's worth considering how much data your system will eventually have. If it's in the 100's or possibly low 1000's of products then `IEnumerable` is Ok, but as systems grow you'll arguably want to consider adding pagination to the queries. Adopting `IQueryable` at a low level can help there rather than trying to pass criteria for page #, page size, along with what details to eager load, sort orders, etc.

Comment: So IEnumerable is more often used to iretate through Lists and while it is good to use IQueryable if working with dbSets/context since it doesnt really take the unneccesary data before filtering. Also im building web api single page app so there are no views. That being said when you say `select (x => ProductSunmaryViewModel ...` i should look at that as a data transfer object wich i need to create in Models folder, right?. Also i need to return Products WITH their category properties. I would then just add Category object as a prooerty to my "vm" aka DTO and then define info in `select` part?

Comment: Yep, that is pretty much the gist of it. :) The Entities reflect the data model as it's stored. The ViewModels reflect the model as the view needs it to be. Projection is the glue that can work with EF's `IQueryable` to use the Entity mappings to build efficient queries to populate a model for the view. Automapper has `ProjectTo` which links into `IQueryable` to build a suitable query and return you the ViewModels once configured.